# Nginx Reverse Proxy display default page instead of remote home page

Tags: linux, nginx, load-balancing, reverse-proxy, devops

I have configured nginx as a reverse proxy and load balancer on a server and on another server there is a web application running. When i access the public URL of nginx it display the default page of RHEL instead of the homepage of the application on remote server. Also, when I add a path in the nginx IP it redirects me to the IP of the application server in the browser instead being the same nginx server. I want the IP to be same as nginx server.

Example:

```
Nginx IP : 52.2.2.2
Remote Ip : 52.2.2.3

Browser 
http://52.2.2.2/admin_portal

IP changes in Broswer
http://52.2.2.3/admin_portal
```

Below are my configuration:
/etc/nginx/conf.d/load_balancer.conf

```
   upstream backend {
      server 10.128.0.2;
   }
   # This server accepts all traffic to port 80 and passes it to the upstream. 
   # Notice that the upstream name and the proxy_pass need to match.
   server {
      listen 80;
      listen [::]:80; 
      location / {
          proxy_pass http://backend;
      }
   }
```

My Nginx configuration file 
/etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}
http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    #gzip  on;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

Can someone please help me

Answer (score 0):

Before you pass the proxy you have to rewrite it.

```
 location / {
                        rewrite ^/reclaimed/Ip / last;
                        proxy_pass http://backend;
                }
```

Comment: tried with the IP and without the IP also, it didn't work for me